# Mathematica erroneously says this integral does not converge

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

*Mathematica* (as of v. 11.1.0) does not recognize that this special case of [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) converges:

```
Integrate[(ArcTan[a*x] - ArcTan[b*x])/x, {x, 0, Infinity}]
(* Integrate::idiv: Integral of ArcTan[a x]/x-ArcTan[b x]/x does not converge 
   on {0,\[Infinity]}.
   Integrate[(ArcTan[a*x] - ArcTan[b*x])/x, {x, 0, Infinity}] *)
```

This should converge because the integrand is well-defined at zero and is $ O(1/x^2)$ as $ x \to \infty $.

Using the formula given, with $ f(x) = \tan^{-1} (x) $, we should have

$$ \int_0^\infty dx\,\frac{\tan^{-1}(a\,x)-\tan^{-1}(b\,x)}{x} = -\frac{\pi}{2} \ln \left(\frac{b}{a}\right) $$

`NIntegrate` crunches through just fine for $ a = 1 $ and $ b = 2 $.

```
NIntegrate[(ArcTan[1*x] - ArcTan[2*x])/x, {x, 0, Infinity}]
(* -1.08879 *)
```

This matches the exact result:

```
-(Pi/2)*Log[2/1] // N
(* -1.08879 *)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The integral does not converge if `a` and `b` are real and have opposite signs:

```
Series[(ArcTan[a*x] - ArcTan[b*x])/x, {x, Infinity, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As @shadowray pointed out, it does converge if `a` and `b` are positive and `Integrate[]` is passed that as an assumption.  It also works with

```
Integrate[(ArcTan[a*x] - ArcTan[b*x])/x, {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a < 0 && b < 0]
```

Answer (score 16):

Although `Integrate` usually finds the condition in which the integral converges,

```
Integrate[Exp[-a x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image]

it's better to provide your own condition in the form of `Assumptions`.

```
Integrate[(ArcTan[a*x] - ArcTan[b*x])/x, {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions->{Re[a]>0, Re[b]>0}]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[(ArcTan[a*x] - ArcTan[b*x])/x, {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions->{Re[a]<0, Re[b]<0}]
```

[image]